# Understanidng if a currency transaction report needs to be filed?

Tags: united-states, irs, like-kind-exchange

I frequently (every week or so) go to an ATM that is in a bank that I do not have an account in. I withdraw $500 and the machine dispenses $20 bills. I then walk up to the teller and exchange the bills for smaller denominations. Today I was asked for my ID and that they needed it for potentially filing a [currency transaction report](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/fin104_ctr.pdf). Ignoring the fact that $500 is way less than the $10,000 reporting requirements<sup>1</sup>, would this type of transaction ever require a CTR? The guidance makes it clear that changing currencies (e.g., Euros to USD) is a transaction that needs to be reported. Is asking a bank to exchange USD bills in one denomination to USD bills in a different denomination considered a transaction?

<sup>1</sup> Potentially they were worried that I might be conducting lots of small transactions, although I would think that if I keep circling through the line they would eventually ask me to stop since I am not an account holder at their bank.

Comment: It wouldn't *require* a CTR.... which is why none were filed before. Why would anyone need $500 in bills smaller than $20s though ???

Comment: @xyious it is for petty cash expenditures, specifically a reoccurring $17 expense.

Comment: The teller may have been referring to a Suspicious Activity Report (SAR); see https://www.fincen.gov/sites/default/files/shared/FinCEN%20SAR%20ElectronicFilingInstructions-%20Stand%20Alone%20doc.pdf.